# How to convert a ImageMagick Image to a Gdi HBITMAP?

Tags: c++, winapi, imagemagick, gdi+

How to convert an `Image` from the lib `Magick++` to a `HBITMAP`?

```
MagickImage image;
try {
    // Read a file into image object 
    image.read("1.png");

    Geometry newSize = Geometry("1920x1080");
    image.resize(newSize);
    // Write the image to a file 
    image.write("2.png");
}
catch (Exception& error_)
{
    cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Magick library, but *I think* you will have to `read()` the RGB pixels from the `Image`, and then create a new `HBITMAP` with the pixel data using `CreateBitmap()`, `CreateDIBitma()` or `CreateDIBSection()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.